# Twitter - info API

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

How to use the twitter geo api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ever since the geoapi shut down, it has been pretty much integrated with the twitter api. The json returned by twitter GET statuses also returns a geo key in the dictionary and geo_enabled key as well.

Here's what you can do to authorize and receive updates via oauth and twitter api (python code)-

```
from twitter import Twitter
from twitter.oauth import OAuth

def get_feeds(screenName):
    twitter = Twitter(auth=OAuth('', '', CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET))
    statuses = twitter.statuses.user_timeline(screen_name=screenName, include_entities=1, include_rts=True)
    print "Got Status"
    return statuses
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you read the Documentation in the link you posted? It says

> Requires Authentication : **TRUE**